# JqueryUI Dialog issue, trying to close dialog within

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am at the moment working on a new project but I have a slight issue, I am using

```
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog().dialog("close");
```

to close a JqueryUI dialog box from within it, aka a user clicks okay and the dialog box should close.

However the above seems to close all open dialog boxes, which is a big issue, is there anything you guys know of that will close a dialog box from within it and only that dialog box.

Also one last thing to note all dialogs ID's are based on time of opening so trying to close them from there ID is near impossible :(.

Thank you for your help and I will look forward to your reply.

Comment: Please show more code. It's likely that there's a variable that refers to the current dialog, possibly `$(this)`, and you can use that instead of `$(".ui-dialog-content")`. But we need to see the context to know what it should be.

Comment: Also, you don't need `.dialog()` before `.dialog("close")`

Comment: Unfortinatly $(this).dialog("close"); does not clost any of the dialogs, also I am running by itself after a $.post so after an ajax request the single dialog would close.

Comment: I asked you to post your code. If you're running it in the AJAX callback function, you need to bind a variable to the dialog, because `this` isn't saved in closures.

Comment: Fixed it thanks for your amazing help the change was $("#submitForm").closest(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close"); I have no idea why this worked the other ones did not but that solved the issue thanks for your amazing help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the comments I finally fixed it I changed the code to

```
$("#submitForm").closest(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Which closed the dialog and not the others that where open.

Comment: If you have an ID on the DIV that you use for the dialog, you can just use that instead: `$("#dialogid").dialog("close");`.

Comment: Thank you, but the ID's are generated randomly so that more then one can be loaded and each wont effect the other :D

Comment: But only one of them has a DIV named `submitForm` in it?

Comment: I still think you should be able to do something using `this`. If you post your code, I'll show you the proper way to correct it.